I want to join center of oval with line. Sort by number oval 1 ---> 2 ----> 3 ----> 1 using x,y coordinates. How can i do?
I want to join center of oval with line. Sort by number oval 1 ---> 2 ----> 3 ----> 1 using x,y coordinates. How can i do ?
coordinates oval 1 is x=50 , y=-50
coordinates oval 2 is x=70 , y=-35
coordinates oval 3 is x=90 , y=-63


How do you want to achieve it? Manually or automatically? Into a new mesh object, or a line object, or what else?

I want to try with manual and automatically sir. And making this new line to a new oblect sir. thank you.

A couple of manual methods:

press Shift C in order to ensure that the 3D cursor is world centered.
Press Shift A to add a Circle mesh, expand its "Adjust Last Operation" panel (black box on the bottom left of the 3D window) and set its vertices number to 3.

Press tab to go to edit mode, select one vertex and write its location values. Repeat for the others vertices.
When done, in object mode you can right click and choose Set Origin > Origin to Geometry if needed.


Add a 3 vertices Circle mesh as described before, in object mode select one ellipse, press Shift S > Cursor to selected, select the triangle, go to edit mode, select one of the vertices, press Shift S > Selection to cursor.

Then go to object mode and repeat for the others 2 ellipses.
